# why do we need a setter when we inject dependency in spring by using xml?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

As we know, in Spring, we can inject fields by 2 ways: setter(xml) and @Autowired.
By using @Autowired, we don't need write a setter. We can inject field just via reflection.
Then my question is:
**why do we still need a setter in XML way?
 Why does not Spring just inject field by reflection?**

Answer (score 0):

Because a Spring Bean is built on top of the JavaBean specification, which define **properties** as paired `public` getter/setter methods following a naming convention. Hence the use of `<property>` in the XML file.

`@Autowired` is allowed on non-`public` members, and hence supports non-JavaBean semantics. A private field without getter/setter methods is not a "property", it is just an instance variable.